# How to make a reply button clicked show a textarea reply field only for one comment using data attribute

Tags: php, jquery

I've been stucked for hours on this, googled but still couldn't resolve it. I will appreciate some guidance please guys.
I’m including a forum-like page on a php project I’m working on where users can comment on a post and then provision for replies to individual comments. My challenge is at the reply part of the code. I placed a reply button after the comments and when clicked fades out to show a textarea which users can type their replies. Now, when I click the reply button, it fades out which is ok, but the textarea appears for all the comments on the post. I tried introducing a data attribute(data-id) with a value of the post Id to bind the reply button clicked to the particular textarea to show but I can’t seems to wrap my head around this. Any help will be appreciated please.
My Php code here:

```
<?php
require("includes/conn.php");
$stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT post_id, user, topic, post, time FROM post_tb ORDER BY time DESC");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $num_of_rows = $result->num_rows;
    if ($num_of_rows > 0){
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $post_id = $row['post_id'];
            $user = $row['user'];
            $topic = $row['topic'];
            $post = $row['post'];
            $time = $row['time'];
            $time = date('M dS, Y g:i A', strtotime($time));
            echo '<div>
                    <div>
                        <h5><strong>'.$user.'</strong></h5><h6>'.$time.'</h6>
                        <h5><strong>'.ucfirst($topic).'</strong></h5>
                        <p data-id="'.$post_id.'">'.$post.'</p>
                    </div>      
                    <div>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary rep" id="but_rep" data-id="'.$post_id.'">Reply</button>
                    </div>
                    <form id="comment_reply" data-id="'.$post_id.'" method="post" action="">
                        <input type="hidden" class="hidden" value="'.$post_id.'" id="post_id">
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="post_rep" id="post_rep"></textarea>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="post_rep_sub">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                <div/>';
            }
        }
?>
```

and my jquery here:

```
<script>
$(document).on('click', 'button#but_rep', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var buttonId = $('form input#post_id').val();
                //$('button#but_rep[data-id="buttonId"]').fadeOut();
                //$('form#comment_reply[data-id="buttonId"]').fadeIn();
                $(this).fadeOut();
                $("form#post_comment_reply").fadeIn();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to use `data` attribute you can just use `.closest()` and `.next()`

```
$(document).on('click' , '.rep' , function(){
   var closestDiv = $(this).closest('div'); // also you can use $(this).parent();
   closestDiv.fadeOut();
   closestDiv.next('form').show();
});
```

> Note: `id="but_rep"` , `id="comment_reply"` Id must be unique .. so use one id for just
>   one element ..use `class=` for more elements

Demo

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click' , 'button.rep' , function(){
     var closestDiv = $(this).closest('div'); // also you can use $(this).parent()
     //closestDiv.fadeOut();
     $('.comment_reply').not(closestDiv.next('.comment_reply')).hide();
     //$('.rep').closest('div').not(closestDiv).show()
     closestDiv.next('form.comment_reply').slideToggle(100);
  });
});
```

```css
form.comment_reply{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary rep" data-id="">Reply</button>
</div>
<form class="comment_reply" data-id="" method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" class="hidden" value="" class="post_id">
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="post_rep" class="post_rep"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" class="post_rep_sub">Submit</button>
</form>

<div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary rep" data-id="">Reply</button>
</div>
<form class="comment_reply" data-id="" method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" class="hidden" value="" class="post_id">
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="post_rep" class="post_rep"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" class="post_rep_sub">Submit</button>
</form>

<div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary rep" data-id="">Reply</button>
</div>
<form class="comment_reply" data-id="" method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" class="hidden" value="" class="post_id">
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="post_rep" class="post_rep"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" class="post_rep_sub">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank u @Mohamed-Yousef. I have used your snippet, but for the life of me the "closest" form only isn't showing up. This part of the script isn't firing.`closestDiv.next('form.comment_reply').slideToggle(100‌​);` I tried replacing the slideToggle(100) with show(), no luck.

Comment: @banky if the `slideToggle` wouldn't work sure `show` will not work either .. please keep eyes on console .. do you got any errors??

Comment: thank you so much for you assistance @Mohamed. i finally got it working.rgds.

Comment: @banky glad your code finally works  .. Have a great day :-) .. Good Luck